# set a new variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have a list with the name of zip files. I want to write a for loop to unzip them into a given directory.

How can I set a variable in bash, which are coming from a part of the zip names?

```
for i in `cat zipfiles.txt`; do
     WIDTH3="${cat zipfiles.txt | rev | cut -c47-54 | rev}"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "part"? You only want to unzip a subset of the files in the list? Or for each iteration of the loop you want to extract part of the current filename?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, which sample of the input file, and the expected output

Comment: You can pipe the value of loop variable `i` in bash using a *here string* `<<< "$i"` - but show us some examples of the required filename transformations - I suspect there's a better way than rev - cut - rev (and the loop over cat is a bad idea as well)

Comment: Last but not least you can replace the whole loop with a `parallel` call. :)

Answer (score 2):

You loop over the lines of `zipfiles.txt`. For each loop you set a variable `$i` with the value of the current line. Then, you cut a part from `cat zipfiles.txt` which makes no sense.

You want to cut from `$i` instead. Also, your syntax is wrong, you have to use `$(any_command)` instead of `${any_command}`.

```
WIDTH3=$(echo "$i" | rev | cut -c47-54 | rev)
```

Anyway, in this case it's better to use `while read [...]` instead of `for ...`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    WIDTH3=$(echo "$line" | rev | cut -c47-54 | rev)
    do_something
done < zipfiles.txt
```

Comment: `while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]` to assure the file's last line is also read if it doesn't have a newline.